# Automate the Boring Stuff Fantasy Inventory

Tags: python

I am working through dictionaries and lists, and my code seems to work pretty well except for increasing the amount in my inventory when the item is already present.

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in dragonLoot:
        if i in inv == True:
            inv[i] = i + 1
        else:
            inv.setdefault(i, 1)
        

    return inv

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inv.items():
        item_total = item_total + inv.get(k, 0)
        print(k, v)
        
        # FILL THIS PART IN
    print('Total number of items: ' + str(item_total))
    # your code goes here

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

Here is my code, when I run it through the visualizer my if statement is skipped even though 'gold coin' is in inv. Not sure how to fix this. The ruby and dagger get added though and it prints.

I tried using a different line but still got the same output.

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in dragonLoot:
        if i == inv[i]:
            inv[i] = i + 1
        else:
            inv.setdefault(i, 1)
```

Comment: Don't unnecessarily compare to `True`. Just `i in inv` is fine and will already yield `True` or `False`, no need to attempt to compare that to `== True`, which will just yield another `True` or `False`.

Comment: ah awesome thank you! Worked perfectly